# jQuery issue - $(this).parent().remove();

Tags: jquery

i found a solution for many problems before here but still cant find answer on this problem. I have a  container and I am adding another  elements inside dynamically with jQuery. Inside that added div's i have a button so I want when i click that button the  and the button to be removed. Here is what i tried so far with no success.

HTML

```
<div id="menuContainer">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="addColumn">add Element (max 5)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="addCard">---</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="delColumn">---</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="delCard">---</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="tblReset">---</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="columns" style="width: 1000px;"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
var columns = $('.column').size();

$('a#addColumn').click(function() {
    if (columns < 5) {                  
    var columnName = prompt('Внесете назив за колоната: ');
    var temp = columns + 1;
    $('<div class="column">' + columnName + '<button id="' + temp + '" style="float:right;" class="btnRemoveColumn">X</button></div>').appendTo('div#columns');
    columns++;
}
else { 
    alert("Имате максимален број на колони во таблата");
}
});

$(".btnRemoveColumn").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});              
});
```

All with the CSS can be tried on external site Fiddle so see how all (not) working. [Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/cXLqK/20/)

Comment: You are trying to bind the event handler to elements that don't exist yet. That won't work.

Comment: can you make the alerts in english? =)

Comment: The first prompt means "Enter the name for the column:" and the alert means "You have maximum number of columns created."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnRemoveColumn", function() {
```

For dynamic elements, events should be delegated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now see it ;) i forgot

Comment: yay thanks :D I'm not very familiar with jQuery that why i stack thanks a lot that works

Comment: @user2058726 Before posting questions, you must prefer language documentation. Maybe It already got solution of your issue.